# How would I evaluate this limit using summation equations?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, summation

This is an alternate way of finding the area under a curve for a certain function:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{3}{n}  \sqrt{9-\left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)^2}$$
This expression would give:
$$\int_0^3 \sqrt{9-x^2} \space dx$$
My question is, how would I evaluate that limit using summation equations such as:
$$\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$$
I understand that this can be solved using regular integration, but how would I arrive at the same answer using the first limit summation equation? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You wouldn't:  there isn't a summation "formula" for such functions.  This is what integration does for us.  We can get formulas for sums on power-functions and so for polynomial functions, for instance, but the integrand here is related to trigonometric functions (since it comes from the equation for a circle), so the function is not algebraic and will not have a "nice" summation formula.

Comment: This clears things up, thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll mention that such limit sums turn up in textbook exercises (and exams...)  and in contest math problems and often must be resolved by the use of integration (though there are some for which there are "tricks").

Comment: You need to choose partition points $x_k=3\sin(k\pi/2n)$ and form Riemann sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})$ and then find its limit as $n\to \infty $.

Comment: As others have remarked the sum in your question can't be evaluated via closed form formula. My previous comment however refers to evaluating the integral in question via a Riemann sum which does have a closed form formula.